# Add two times in MM:SS format and return as string to maximum precision

Tags: c#, .net, string, addition

I want to write a function which adds 2 strings, one in format MM:ss and another is given as seconds only then make the addition (taking care of the extra seconds) returns them in same format with maximum levels of precision. 
// ex: "1:30" + "65" = "2:35"

I have tried from my side but I think it can be made more generic, please see the code

```
public static string maxLevel(string s1, string s2)
        {
            string[] parts1 = null;
            string[] parts2 = null;

            if (s1.Contains(":"))
            {
                parts1 = s1.Split(':');
            }

            if (s2.Contains(":"))
            {
                parts2 = s2.Split(':');
            }


            int minutes1 = 0;
            int seconds1 = 0;
            int minutes2;
            int seconds2 = 0;
            int newSeconds = 0;
            int newMinutes = 0;
            int carry = 0;

            if (parts1 != null && parts1.Length > 1)
            {
                minutes1 = Convert.ToInt32(parts1[0]);
               // int HoursInminutes = (12 + (minutes % 60)) * 60;
                seconds1 = Convert.ToInt32(parts1[1]);
            }

            else
            {
                seconds1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1);
                int minutes = seconds1 / 60;
                if (minutes >= 1)
                {
                    carry = seconds1 - 60;
                    //newSeconds = seconds2 + carry;
                }

                newMinutes = minutes;
                newSeconds = carry;
            }

            if (parts2 != null && parts2.Length > 1)
            {
                minutes2 = Convert.ToInt32(parts2[0]);
                seconds2 = Convert.ToInt32(parts2[1]);
                //newMinutes = minutes2;
                newMinutes += minutes2;
                newSeconds += seconds2;
            } 


            else
            {
                seconds2 = Convert.ToInt32(s2);
                int minutes = seconds2/60;
                if(minutes >= 1)
                {
                    carry = seconds2 - 60;
                    newSeconds = seconds1 + carry;
                    newMinutes = minutes1 + minutes;
                }
                else
                {
                    carry = seconds2 - seconds1;
                    newSeconds = carry;
                    newMinutes = 1 + minutes1;
                }


            }

            return newMinutes + ":" + newSeconds;

        }
```

When I change s1 to 55 secs and s2 to 1:30 then this code doesn't work.
I think it needs some modification, can somebody please help or show me the correct way in C#

Comment: The **[Timespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)** type is made for working with times and has `Parse()`, `TryParse()` and `Subtract()` methods

Comment: Says "_adds 2 strings in format MM:ss_". Then proceeds to show an example _"1:30" + "65" = "2:35"_ where only one of the 2 strings added is in mm:ss format... Wat? Also, what about something like `"51:20" + "56:12"`?

Comment: Yes, one string is given in MM:SS and another is given as only secods (65), so while adding we have take care of that --> (1:30 + 65) = 2:35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to allow the user to specify more than 59 seconds (and/or minutes), I don't think `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` will work, because you can't pass more than `59` seconds or minutes to it. Those fields must be `0-59`.

However, you can write your own custom parser that splits the input string on the colon character (`:`) and then uses `int.TryParse` to try to parse the resulting parts to integers, and then you can use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` to pass any number of seconds to create a new `TimeSpan` object, and you can use the `.Add` method to add another timespan created from the minutes portion, if it was specified.

First we can write a method that will return a `TimeSpan` from a string in the format "[integer]" or "[integer]:[integer]":

```
public static TimeSpan CustomParse(string input)
{
    // Split the string on the ':' character
    var parts = input?.Split(':');

    // Make sure we have something to work with
    if (parts == null || parts.Length == 0) 
        throw new FormatException("input format must be \"%m:%s\" or \"%s\"");

    int seconds;

    // Only a single number represents seconds
    if (parts.Length == 1)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out seconds))
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
        }
    }
    // Otherwise the first number is minutes and the second one is seconds
    else
    {
        int minutes;
        if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out minutes) &&
            int.TryParse(parts[1], out seconds))
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));
        }
    }

    // If we haven't returned anything yet, there was an error in the format
    throw new FormatException("input format must be \"%m:%s\" or \"%s\"");
}
```

Then we can write another function that takes in two strings, converts them to timespans using our method above, and returns the result of adding them together as a string:

```
public static string Add(string s1, string s2)
{
    return CustomParse(s1).Add(CustomParse(s2)).ToString("%m\\:%s");
}
```

Now we can test this out using your sample strings:

```
private static void Main()
{
    string first = "1:30";
    string second = "65";
    string result = Add(first, second);

    Console.WriteLine($"{first} + {second} = {result}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: Image showing that the result is 2:35]

Comment: Great answer! Thank you !